# Python/python-docx - can't create a blank file with certain settings

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx

I'm trying to create a `.docx` document using `python-docx`, but it doesn't work. I want the document to contain no text and have the following settings:

10.5-pt Times New Roman font

No spacing before or after paragraphs

Line spacing set to 1.5 lines.

```
from docx import Document
from docx.enum.text import WD_LINE_SPACING 
from docx.shared import Pt

document = Document()

paragraph = document.add_paragraph()

#paragraph.line_spacing_rule = SINGLE

paragraph_format = paragraph.paragraph_format

paragraph_format.space_before = Pt(0)
paragraph_format.space_after = Pt(0)

run = document.add_paragraph().add_run()
font = run.font

font.name = 'Times New Roman'
font.size = Pt(10.5)

document.save('test.docx')
```

As you can see, I've had to comment out the line about the line spacing, since it throws an error. All of the above code has been taken essentially verbatim from the `python-docx` manual.

The error the commented-out line throws is this, for reference:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\create_blank.py", line 9, in <module>
    paragraph.line_spacing_rule = SINGLE
NameError: name 'SINGLE' is not defined
```

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: I've edited it in to the question, at the end.

Comment: Well, SINGLE indeed doesn't seem to be defined or imported anywhere. I think it should be `WD_LINE_SPACING.SINGLE`. See http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/enum/WdLineSpacing.html

Comment: @MarcAdler As the error suggests, `SINGLE` isn't defined. In addition to what Shovalt said, `WD_LINE_SPACING.SINGLE` seems to be the default setting.

Comment: I see. I needed to put `WD_LINE_SPACING.SINGLE` in and not just `SINGLE`.

Comment: That doesn't fix it, though. When I open the resulting document, the only settings that appear to have taken are the 0 space before/after paragraphs. Everything else is Word 2016's default settings: 11-pt Cambria, with "multiple" "1.5" line spacing. 

It seems like `python-docx` somehow isn't able to overcome Word's default settings.

Comment: I am not familiar with this particular package, so I don't have an immediate solution, but let's work at it together. 1) why are you doing `run = document.add_paragraph().add_run()` instead of simply `run = paragraph.add_run()` (using the already defined paragraph)? 2) Are you sure the 0 space takes effect, meaning this does override the default? Try removing this part of the code and seeing that the result changes as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I basically just Frankensteined all the code examples I could find on the documentation site together. I've made the change you suggested re `paragraph` and it still runs. I also commented out the parts about 0 space, and they do work, i.e., when I comment those lines out, the spacing is not 0.